# Barcode using zint library

Tags: c, barcode

In the code snippet below I am attempting a barcode using zint library. The data that I have is represented by the structure barcode_print_t.
The `data` field in an integer (represented as a byte array) should be converted into barcode based on the symbology specified.
My question is there a way to get the buffer that contains the barcode data (meaning the data that you get by converting the integer into barcode) so that I can send it directly to the printer.

```
typedef struct barcode_printing { 
    BYTE barcode_symbology; 
    uint16_t barcode_width; 
    uint16_t barcode_height;
    BYTE data_length;
    BYTE data[1024];
} barcode_print_t;

memcpy(&barcode->barcode_symbology, &mo->pData[i+1], sizeof(BYTE));

uint16_t barcode_size = 0;

barcode_size = (mo->pData[i + 4] << 8) | (mo->pData[i + 5]);

memcpy(&barcode->barcode_width, &barcode_size, sizeof(uint16_t)); 
memcpy(&barcode->data_length, &mo->pData[i + 7], sizeof(BYTE)); 
memcpy(&barcode->data, &mo->pData[i +8], barcode->data_length);

printf("barcode symbology --> %02x \n", barcode->barcode_symbology); 

settings = ZBarcode_Create();
```

Comment: Are you really sending the data directly to the printer? Is it an ESC/POS printer or something? Usually you'd generate a PostScript or PDF file, then ask your OS to print it… If you're communicating directly with the printer yourself the answer would depend on that protocol.

Comment: @nemequ - it is an ESC printer.

Comment: Okay, so most ESC/POS printers will be able to generate barcodes for some symbologies, you should probably just use that instead of zint if you can. Otherwise you'll probably need to have zint generate a bitmap then write that to the printer. Unfortunately this stuff tends to be manufacturer-specific, so you'll need to get documentation from the manufacturer about what symbologies or image formats are supported and how they'll need to be encoded.

Comment: If you end up using zint to encode an image, see https://sourceforge.net/p/zint/code/ci/master/tree/frontend/main.c#l740 for an example of how to use the API. Basically, it looks like you need to set "outfile.bmp", then `ZBarcode_Encode`, then read the file.

Comment: FWIW, for the manufacturer I'm familiar with `1d 6b` is the "print bar code" command for the manufacturer I'm familiar with. I can't provide full documentation on how to use it thanks to an NDA ☹.

Comment: @nemequ - what is `1d 6b`

Comment: The first two bytes, in hex, of the command to print a barcode. See https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf (look for the "printing bar codes" section), though the list of supported symbologies will vary depending on the manufacturer and model (the ones I'm familiar with support a lot more symbologies).